# stop gradients flowing in a joint loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent, backpropagation, loss-function

I have an input tensor

`data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])`

which will be embedded by

```
embedding_matrix = tf.get_variable("embedding_matrix", [5,3], tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
input_vectors = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=embedding_matrix, ids=data)
```

I perform a linear transformation on the input vector using `output1_weights` to get `network_output1`

```
output1_weights = tf.get_variable("output1", [3,4], tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
network_output1 = tf.matmul(input_vectors, output1_weights)
```

The loss will be very standard stuff

```
loss1 = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=output1, logits=network_output1)
```

Now I want to use the logits `network_output1` as input to compute another linear transformation

```
output2_weights = tf.get_variable("output2", [4,5], tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
network_output2 = tf.matmul(network_output1, output2_weights)
```

Again cross-entropy loss on the second output

```
loss2 = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=output2, logits=network_output2)
```

Here is what I want to achieve. In a joint loss setting I want to only back-prop the gradient of `output1_weights` when minimizing the loss of `loss1` and only the gradient of `output2_weights` when minimizing `loss2`. In other words, when optimizing `loss2` I don't want the gradients to flow all the back to tamper `output1_weights`. I am aware of the `compute_gradients` function in optimizer class which can take an argument `var_list`, but it seems it can not stop the gradients flowing for separate losses. Also I can consider separating the losses and minimize them individually, which will also be a bad solution in my setting.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is select a trainable variable and assign it to `var_list`.

First count the trainable variables of your different loss.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
output1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
output2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

embedding_matrix = tf.get_variable("embedding_matrix", [5,3], tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
input_vectors = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=embedding_matrix, ids=data)
# count 
params_num0 = len(tf.trainable_variables())

output1_weights = tf.get_variable("output1", [3,4], tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
network_output1 = tf.matmul(input_vectors, output1_weights)
# count 
params_num1 = len(tf.trainable_variables())
loss1 = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=output1, logits=network_output1)

output2_weights = tf.get_variable("output2", [4,5], tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
network_output2 = tf.matmul(network_output1, output2_weights)
loss2 = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=output2, logits=network_output2)
```

Then print them and all trainable variables.

```
params = tf.trainable_variables()
print(params_num0)
print(params_num1)
print(params)

# 1
# 2
# [<tf.Variable 'embedding_matrix:0' shape=(5, 3) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'output1:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'output2:0' shape=(4, 5) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

You can see that there are three trainable variables: `loss1` for the second, and `loss2` for the third.

```
# if you want to back-prop the gradient of embedding_matrix,
# params1 = params[:params_num1]
# params2 = params[:params_num0] + params[params_num1:]
params1 = params[params_num0:params_num1]
params2 = params[params_num1:]
print(params1)
print(params2)

# [<tf.Variable 'output1:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32_ref>]
# [<tf.Variable 'output2:0' shape=(4, 5) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Next, Specify the updated gradient for the corresponding variable.

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)
grads_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss1,var_list=params1)
grads_vars2 = opt.compute_gradients(loss2,var_list=params2)
print(grads_vars)
print(grads_vars2)

# [(<tf.Tensor 'gradients/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'output1:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32_ref>)]
# [(<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/MatMul_1_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(4, 5) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'output2:0' shape=(4, 5) dtype=float32_ref>)]
```

Finally, we can use `apply_gradients()` to update trainable variable.

```
train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads_vars+grads_vars2)
```

**Experiment**

```
data_np = np.random.normal(size=(100))
output1_np = np.random.randint(0,4,size=(100))
output2_np = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100))
feed_dict_v = {data: data_np, output1: output1_np, output2: output2_np}

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(2):
        print("epoch:{}".format(i))
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict_v)
        print("embedding_matrix value:\n",sess.run(embedding_matrix, feed_dict=feed_dict_v))
        print("output1_weights value:\n",sess.run(output1_weights, feed_dict=feed_dict_v))
        print("output2_weights value:\n",sess.run(output2_weights, feed_dict=feed_dict_v))
```

The result:

```
epoch:0
embedding_matrix value:
 [[ 0.7646786  -0.44221798 -1.6374763 ]
 [-0.4061512  -0.70626575  0.09637168]
 [ 1.3499098   0.38479885 -0.10424987]
 [-1.3999717   0.67008936  1.8843309 ]
 [-0.11357951 -1.1893668   1.1205566 ]]
output1_weights value:
 [[-0.22709225  0.70598644  0.10429419 -2.2737694 ]
 [-0.6364337  -0.08602498  1.9750406   0.8664075 ]
 [ 0.3656631  -0.25182125 -0.14689662 -0.03764082]]
output2_weights value:
 [[ 0.00554644 -0.49370843 -0.75148153  0.6645286   1.0131303 ]
 [ 0.21612553  0.07851358  0.05937392 -0.3236267  -0.8081816 ]
 [ 0.82237226  0.17242427 -1.3059226  -1.1134574   0.22402465]
 [-1.6996336  -0.58993673 -0.7071007   0.8407903   0.62416744]]
epoch:1
embedding_matrix value:
 [[ 0.7646786  -0.44221798 -1.6374763 ]
 [-0.4061512  -0.70626575  0.09637168]
 [ 1.3499098   0.38479885 -0.10424987]
 [-1.3999717   0.67008936  1.8843309 ]
 [-0.11357951 -1.1893668   1.1205566 ]]
output1_weights value:
 [[-0.21710345  0.6959941   0.11408082 -2.2637703 ]
 [-0.64639646 -0.07603455  1.9650643   0.85640883]
 [ 0.35567763 -0.24182947 -0.15682784 -0.04763966]]
output2_weights value:
 [[ 0.01553426 -0.5036415  -0.7415529   0.65454334  1.003145  ]
 [ 0.20613036  0.08847766  0.04942677 -0.31363514 -0.7981894 ]
 [ 0.8323502   0.16245098 -1.2959852  -1.1234138   0.21408063]
 [-1.6896346  -0.59990865 -0.6971453   0.8307945   0.6141711 ]]
```

You can see that `embedding_matrix` has never changed.`output1_weights` and `output2_weights` only update the corresponding gradient.

**Add**

In fact, you can combine `loss1` and `loss2` on `output2_weights`. For example:

```
grads_vars3 = opt.compute_gradients(loss1+loss2,var_list=params2)
```

You will find that `grads_vars2` and `grads_vars3` are equal when `loss1` and `loss2` are combined by addition. The reason is that the gradient of `loss1` does not flow to `output2_weights` in `loss1+loss2`. But in the following cases, `grads_vars2` and `grads_vars3` are not equal when `loss1` and `loss2` are combined by multiplication.

```
grads_vars3 = opt.compute_gradients(loss1*loss2,var_list=params2)
```

The above cases mean that we can combine losses for corresponding trainable variables according to our own needs.

In your scenario, `network_output2` needs to use `network_output1`, so we have to specify loss. If `network_output2` does not depend on `network_output1`, we can directly optimize `loss1 + loss2`.

**About gradients**

```
input = tf.constant([[1,2,3]],tf.float32)
label1 = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4]],tf.float32)
label2 = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5]],tf.float32)

weight1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(12,dtype=tf.float32),[3,4])
output1 = tf.matmul(input , weight1)
loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(output1 - label1)

weight2 = tf.reshape(tf.range(20,dtype=tf.float32),[4,5])
output2 = tf.matmul(output1 , weight2)
loss2 = tf.reduce_sum(output2 - label2)

grad1 = tf.gradients(loss1,weight1)
grad2 = tf.gradients(loss2,weight2)
grad3 = tf.gradients(loss1+loss2,weight2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(grad1))
    print(sess.run(grad2))
    print(sess.run(grad3))

# [array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [2., 2., 2., 2.],
#        [3., 3., 3., 3.]], dtype=float32)]
# [array([[32., 32., 32., 32., 32.],
#        [38., 38., 38., 38., 38.],
#        [44., 44., 44., 44., 44.],
#        [50., 50., 50., 50., 50.]], dtype=float32)]
# [array([[32., 32., 32., 32., 32.],
#        [38., 38., 38., 38., 38.],
#        [44., 44., 44., 44., 44.],
#        [50., 50., 50., 50., 50.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: I think I made it very clear that I want a joint loss instead of separate losses, which I already laid out a solution myself in my question *Also I can consider separating the losses and minimize them individually, which will also be a bad solution in my setting.*. By the way you don't need to specify a `var_list` when minimizing `loss1`.

Comment: @user1935724 You should first describe the mathematical relationship between `joint loss` and `loss1`,`loss2`. Add or multiply?

Comment: I thought joint loss implies add.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! Does it mean there is really no way we can combine the loss first and control how gradients can flow.

Comment: @user1935724 Please see the answer I added

Comment: `grads_vars3 = opt.compute_gradients(loss1+loss2,var_list=params2)` does not seem to be correct. Again `loss1` should let the gradient flow to `output1_weights` and `loss2` should do to `output2_weights`. The code you give above does not do that.

Comment: @user1935724 You may not understand tensorflow's support for gradient computing. Even if `loss1 + loss2` is used here,  the gradient of `output2_weights` is only determined by `loss2` when `loss1` and `loss2` are combined by addition.. Let me give you an example in the answer.

Comment: You need to go back to revisit your engineering mathematics since you don't even seem to understand minimizing `loss2` will propagate the gradients back to `output1_weights`.

Comment: @user1935724 Please read my answers and comments in detail, I never said `loss2` didn't affect the gradient of `output1_weights`. My example shows that `loss1` does not affect the gradient of `output2_weights`.  As for my previous code, I have eliminated the gradient effect of `loss2` on `output1_weights`.

Comment: where is the part of controlling `loss2` not to propagate the gradients to `output1_weights` in your joint loss?

Comment: @user1935724 `grads_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss1,var_list=params1)
grads_vars2 = opt.compute_gradients(loss2,var_list=params2)`

Comment: ...that's not a joint loss. `grads_vars3 = opt.compute_gradients(loss1+loss2,var_list=params2)` is a joint loss which is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206386/discussion-between-giser-yugang-and-user1935724).